# Why I dont need to use nonlocal in this situation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def a():
    mem=['a']
    def b():
      mem=[]                                                                                                    
      print(str(mem))
    return b
a()()
```

Why this code will work even if I won't add `nonlocal mem` in b function?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It won't, not if you're expecting `mem` to be altered in `a`'s scope.

Comment: What do you mean by "work"? What output are you getting, and what output would count as "not working"?

Comment: I was trying to change the mem from 'a function', I thought I should get error that I cannot assign to mem cause It is not defined

Comment: But you don't, so it's probably "not working".

Comment: @MikeL: But it *is* defined, you just assigned an empty list to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've assigned an empty list object to `mem` within `b`, so it is defined. The lookup succeeds when printing.

Note that `mem` is a *local* name in `b`; the `mem` local in `a` is entirely unaffected, the two names are entirely separate.

If you expected `a`'s `mem` to change, you would either mark `mem` in `b` as non-local, or you can avoid assigning by changing the `mem` object directly:

```
def a():
    mem = ['a']
    def b():
        mem[:] = []
        print(str(mem))
    return b
a()()
```

Here the name `mem` is not assigned to; instead the indices *inside* the `mem` list are altered. Because there is no assignment to the name `mem` in `b`, it is not a local.

This works because list objects themselves are mutable; you can interact with the object and change the contents.

Comment: I was trying to change the mem from 'a function'

Comment: @MikeL: then you'd need to mark it `nonlocal`. Or change the list object directly instead of rebinding `mem` in `b`.

Comment: Is there any function that can tell me where those lists are located?, for example: print(func(mem)) -> b.mem (without nonlocal in b function)

Comment: @MikeL: If you are writing code where you no longer know if you are using a local or a non-local you need to simplify things. :-) You can look at the `inspect` module to see what information is available on code objects and function objects, together with the `locals()` and `globals()` there is a lot of introspection you can do here.

Comment: If I do that `def b(): nonlocal mem ; mem=[]` there is local mem in b? or only one mem exists(in a)?

Comment: @MikeL: then you *know* `x` is a `nonlocal` because you just marked it as non local.

Comment: @MikeL: `mem` is *visible* in `b`. It is a closure value. It is only one object referenced in `a` and as a closure in `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are a mutable datatype so if you pass a reference to them into a method, the method will modify the orginal list always because only one actual lists exists. To avoid this you can use a .copy() method to create a duplicate list under a different name.

See this link for reference:
https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-functions-modify-lists-dictionaries-python/